# Vue Infinite Loop Bug?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When working with Vue, I encountered a situation that created an infinite refresh loop.  To help debug, I started a new vue project (version 2) and created the two very simple files below.  If you uncomment the {{counter}} in the app.vue file, it goes into an infinite loop.  The watcher in the child file keeps thinking that the scope prop is changing, but it is effectively a constant for this simplified test case.  I am pretty sure this is a vue bug, but before filing it, I wanted to see if anyone else has any ideas.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
       <HelloWorld 
         :scope="{}" 
         @counter="counter++;"
       />
       <br>
      <p>
        Parent Counter: 
        <!-- {{counter}} If you uncomment this line it loops-->
      </p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
export default{
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  },
    name: "top",
    data () {
        return {
            counter: 0,
        };
    },  
};
</script>
```

hellowWorld.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      Hello World From Child
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default{
    name: "helloWorld",
  props: {
        scope:          Object,
    },

    data () {
        return{
            counter: 0,
            mounted: 0
        };
    },

    watch: {
        scope:{
            handler: function(){
                console.log("helloWorld scope Changed");
                this.update();
            },
            immediate: true,
            deep: true,
        },
    },

    methods: {
        update: async function(){
            this.counter ++;
            console.log("HelloWorld UPDATE CALLED: ", this.counter);
            this.$emit("counter", 1);
        },

    
    }
 };

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside HelloWorld, you watch the `:scope` prop and emit a counter event every time scope changes.

The issue comes from the throw-away object you put into `:scope`, in combination with the update event causing a redraw:

```html
<HelloWorld 
  :scope="{}" 
  @counter="counter++;"
/>
```

Every time the parent component gets re-rendered, a new object is put into HelloWorld's `:scope` prop. Which triggers the watcher, leading to a `counter` event, which causes a redraw of the parent, and here we go.

But it is doing exactly what you told it to do, the infinite loop is similar to the one you get from writing `while (true)` - it is not a bug.

When you put an object from a variable into `:scope`, the loop goes away (since the same object is put into HelloWorld after a redraw).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I understand how the loop is happening, but what I don't know is why rendering the count would cause the redraw of the HelloWorld component and thus cause the loop.

Comment: It's basically a demonstration how well Vue's change detection works. As long as you don't use `count` in the template, there is no need for Vue to redraw anything, so the loop isn't triggered. Only when you actually print it, the DOM gets updated and the loop gets going.

Comment: Ok, the DOM refresh is more course than I thought.  I thought it would only refresh the count display, not the HelloWorld component.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the update function:

```
  methods: {
    update() {
      if (!this.counter) {
        this.counter++;
        this.$emit("counter", 1);
      }
     }
   }
```

any change to the counter will trigger a re-render of the parent component and child component,this re-rendering causes the scope prop to triggering the watcher in the child component to an infinite loop.